# Create elastic/gooey animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I've seen a lot of "gooey" animations for HTML5/CSS and have been trying to find something similar for Android. What I'm looking for is to make something like the links below:

http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeGooeyEffects/menu.html

http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeGooeyEffects/pagination.html

Scaling and translating is no problem but is there a way (other than importing some game lib) to get the "connecting part" when for example separating one dot into two?

Answer (score 2):

Skip to the last 10 min of [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71ISWyJPSEY&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_HyE1QX9heAgTPdAMqc50z&index=8) for good information about material motion.

Checking out the [presenter's library,](https://bitbucket.org/ntkachov/gooeybits) it is a work in progress that is worth the time. He is using `Canavs.bitmapMesh` to give drawables that gooeyness you want. There is still lot of work needs to done.